# How does Java find spark, Hadoop and AWS jars in Intellij

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am running spark application on IntelliJ in Java. I have added spark, Hadoop and AWS dependencies in pom.xml but somehow AWS credentials are not being loaded.

The exact error I get is `Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint`

Below are my .java and pom.xml files.

```
SparkSession spark  = SparkSession
                    .builder()
                    .master("local") .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")            .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
                    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", AWS_KEY)
                    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", AWS_SECRET_KEY)
                    .getOrCreate();

            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
            Dataset<Row> dF = spark.read().load("s3a://bucket/abc.parquet");
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.417</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am stuck in this for a while and tried all available solutions. I added export AWS keys in my environment.

Is there any other way you specify jars or keys for java, considering there is no java spark shell like python or Scala and pom.xml is the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that you have to add AWS creds in SparkContext only and not SparkSession.

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", AWS_KEY);
sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", AWS_SECRET_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

The main point is to add AWS credentials to your Hadoop configurations. 
No need of creating a separate JavaSparkContext. You can directly modify the sparkContext and add AWS credentials in the following way:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                     .master("local")
                     .appName("AWSFileRead")
                     .getOrCreate();

spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", AWS_KEY);
spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", AWS_SECRET_KEY);

Dataset<Row> awsFileDataset = spark.read().option("header", "true")
                .csv("s3a://your_bucket_name/file_name.csv");
```